# Some simple Ruby questions - iterators, blocks, and symbols

Tags: ruby

My background is in PHP and C#, but I'd really like to learn RoR. To that end, I've started reading the official documentation.  I have some questions about some code examples.

The first is with iterators:

```
class Array
  def inject(n)
    each { |value| n = yield(n, value) }
    n
  end

  def sum
    inject(0) { |n, value| n + value }
  end

  def product
    inject(1) { |n, value| n * value }
  end
end
```

I understand that `yield` means "execute the associated block here."  What's throwing me is the `|value| n =` part of the `each`.  The other blocks make more sense to me as they seem to mimic C# style lambdas:

```
public int sum(int n, int value)
{
    return Inject((n, value) => n + value);
}
```

But the first example is confusing to me.

The other is with symbols.  When would I want to use them?  And why can't I do something like:

```
class Example
  attr_reader @member

  # more code
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`inject` or `reduce`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method, `n` represents an accumulated value; this means the result of every iteration is accumulated in the `n` variable. This could be, as is in your example, the sum or product of the elements in the array.

`yield` returns the result of the block, which is stored in `n` and used in the next iterations. This is what makes the result "cumulative."

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
a.sum  # inject(0) { |n, v| n + v }
# n == 0; n = 0 + 1
# n == 1; n = 1 + 2
# n == 3; n = 3 + 3
 => 6
```

Also, to compute the sum you could also have written `a.reduce :+`. This works for any binary operation. If your method is named `symbol`, writing `a.reduce :symbol` is the same as writing `a.reduce { |n, v| n.symbol v }`.

`attr` and company are actually methods. Under the hood, they dynamically define the methods for you. It uses the symbol you passed to work out the names of the instance variable and the methods. `:member` results in the `@member` instance variable and the `member` and `member =` methods.

The reason you can't write `attr_reader @member` is because `@member` isn't an object in itself, nor can it be converted to a symbol; it actually tells ruby to fetch the value of the  instance variable `@member` of the `self` object, which, at class scope, is the class itself.

To illustrate:

```
class Example
  @member = :member
  attr_accessor @member
end

e = Example.new
e.member = :value
e.member
 => :value
```

Remember that accessing unset instance variables yields `nil`, and since the `attr` method family accepts only symbols, you get: `TypeError: nil is not a symbol`.

Regarding [Symbol](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html) usage, you can *sort of* use them like strings. They make excellent hash keys because equal symbols always refer to the same object, unlike strings.

```
:a.object_id == :a.object_id
 => true
'a'.object_id == 'a'.object_id
 => false
```

They're also commonly used to refer to method names, and [can actually be converted to `Proc`s](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc), which can be passed to methods. This is what allows us to write things like `array.map &:to_s`.

Check out [this article](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2007/01/20/13-ways-of-looking-at-a-ruby-symbol) for more interpretations of the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

For the definition of `inject`, you're basically setting up chained blocks. Specifically, the variable n in `{|value| n = yield(n, value)}` is essentially an accumulator for the block passed to `inject`. So, for example, for the definition of `product`, `inject(1) {|value| n * value}`, let's assume you have an array `my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]`. When you call `my_array.product`, you start by calling `inject` with n = 1. `each` yields to the block defined in `inject`, which in turns yields to the block passed to `inject` itself with n (1) and the first value in the array (1 as well, in this case). This block, `{|n, value| n * value}` returns 1 == 1 * 1, which is set it `inject`'s n variable. Next, 2 is yielded from each, and the block defined in `inject` block yields as `yield(1, 2)`, which returns 2 and assigns it to n. Next 3 is yielded from `each`, the block yields the values (2, 3) and returns 6, which is stored in n for the next value, and so forth. Essentially, tracking the overall value agnostic of the calculation being performed in the specialised routines (`sum` and `product`) allows for generalization. Without that, you'd have to declare e.g.

```
def sum
  n = 0
  each {|val| n += val}
end

def product
  n = 1
  each {|val| n *= val}
end
```

which is annoyingly repetitive.

For your second question, `attr_reader` and its family are themselves methods that are defining the appropriate accessor routines using `define_method` internally, in a process called metaprogramming; they are not language statements, but just plain old methods. These functions expect to passed a symbol (or, perhaps, a string) that gives the name of the accessors you're creating. You could, in theory, use instance variables such as `@member` here, though it would be the value to which `@member` points that would be passed in and used in `define_method`. For an example of how these are implemented, [this page](http://www.raulparolari.com/Ruby2/attr_accessor) shows some examples of attr_* methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
def inject(accumulator)
  each { |value| accumulator = yield(accumulator, value) }
  accumulator
end
```

This is just yielding the current value of `accumulator` and the array item to inject's block and then storing the result back into accumulator again.

```
class Example
  attr_reader @member
end
```

`attr_reader` is just a method whose argument is the name of the accessor you want to setup. So, in a contrived way you could do

```
class Example
  @ivar_name = 'foo'
  attr_reader @ivar_name
end
```

to create an getter method called `foo`

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion with the first example may be due to your reading `|value| n` as a single expression, but it isn't.

This reformatted version might be clearer to you:

```
 def inject(n)
   each do |value|
     n = yield(n, value)
   end
   return n
 end
```

`value` is an element in the array, and it is yielded with n to whatever block is passed to `inject`, the result of which is set to `n`. If that's not clear, read up on the `each` method, which takes a block and yields each item in the array to it. Then it should be clearer how the accumulation works.

`attr_reader` is less weird when you consider that it is a method for generating accessor methods. It's not an accessor in itself. It doesn't need to deal with the `@member` variable's value, just its name. `:member` is just the interned version of the string 'member', which is the name of the variable.

You can think of symbols as lighter weight strings, with the additional bonus that every equal label is the same object - `:foo.object_id == :foo.object_id`, whereas `'foo'.object_id != 'foo'.object_id`, because each 'foo' is a new object. You can try that for yourself in `irb`.  Think of them as labels, or primitive strings. They're surprisingly useful and come up a lot, e.g. for metaprogramming or as keys in hashes. As pointed out elsewhere, calling `object.send :foo` is the same as calling `object.foo`

It's probably worth reading some early chapters from the ['pickaxe' book](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/) to learn some more ruby, it will help you understand and appreciate the extra stuff rails adds.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand where to use symbols and where its not..
Symbol is especially used to represent something. Ex: :name, :age like that. Here we are not going to perform any operations using this.
String are used only for data processing. Ex: 'a = name'. Here I gonna use this variable 'a' further for other string operations in ruby.
Moreover, symbol is more memory efficient than strings and it is immutable. That's why ruby developer's prefers symbols than string.

You can even use inject method to calculate sum as (1..5).to_a.inject(:+)